# DBpedia memory error

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

I'm running a query on DBpedia and come across the following error:

> Virtuoso 42000 Error SQ200: The memory pool size 400097280 reached the limit 400000000 bytes, try to increase the MaxMemPoolSize ini setting.

I'm running the query as a `SERVICE` query from a triplestore. How do I manage the `MaxMemPoolSize` setting if I don't want to change the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that the entry `MaxMemPoolSize` in the `virtuoso.ini` file associated with the DBpedia-hosting [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) instance has to be increased to allow your query to run.  That increase is only possible if the instance is hosted by you.

Obviously, if you're using the [official publicly-accessible DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), you can't increase this setting. You *can* spin up your own mirror, [manually](https://joernhees.de/blog/2015/11/23/setting-up-a-linked-data-mirror-from-rdf-dumps-dbpedia-2015-04-freebase-wikidata-linkedgeodata-with-virtuoso-7-2-1-and-docker-optional/) or with a [pre-populated and automatically updated Amazon AMI (usage fees apply)](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015), and increase this (and other usage limits) as you like.

*(ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) and the [DBpedia AMI](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015), provides the [DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql), and employs me.)*

Answer (score 3):

That does only work if the triple store, and here it's Virtuoso is hosted by yourself. Obviously, if you're using the official DBpedia endpoint, you can'T do anything but setting it up on your own machine/cluster.

Otherwise, the entry `MaxMemPoolSize` in the in the `virtuoso.ini` file has to be increased